# View code in Excel - Import_Journals

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic

I'm trying to look at some VB code in an Excel macro. This code is executed on a button click:

```
Private Sub ImportSelected_Click()
    Call Import_Journals("SELECTED", "IMPORT")
End Sub
```

I want to see what `Import_Journals` does, so I right-click on `Import_Journals` and select `Identify`, I get:

```
Identifier under cursor is not recognized.
```

Is this a built-in entity?
How do I find out what this does?

Comment: Press F8 to start stepping through your code, it will take you to the definition of `Import_Journals`.

Comment: It turns out the there is another excel that should come along with my current file that has the function.

Comment: @Kyle: If you could combine my comment and your comment into and answer, I will check it off and close this question. Thanks!